# VB.Net how to append a dir to the Path env variable in code

Tags: vb.net, path, environment-variables

I would like to offer the users of my app an easy way to update the environment variables that the app requires.
I have no problem getting and setting environment variables in general, that all works.

The problem is when I update the Path environment variable all the variable names within it are lost. For example the entry %JAVA_HOME%\bin gets expanded into the complete path when I read it so I cannot write it back as it was before being expanded.

I have tried setting the variable with %PATH%;myaddedpath . This works in a shell but within code it literally writes %PATH% into the environment variable!!

```
Private Sub AddStringtoPath(value As String)
        Dim lPathVar As String
        For a As Integer = 0 To lstPathList.Items.Count - 1
            If lstPathList.Items(a) = value Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                lPathVar = lPathVar + ";" + lstPathList.Items(a)
            End If
        Next
        lstPathList.Items.Add(value)
        lPathVar = lPathVar.Substring(1, lPathVar.Length - 1)
        lPathVar = lPathVar + ";" + value

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", lPathVar + value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine)
        RefreshFormData()
    End Sub
```

This code parses a listbox that contains the entries of the path variable adding them to a string as it goes if it gets to the end the string is not already there so it goes on to add it to the path variable.

As it stands it works in so far as it writes the existing lines back into the Path variable correctly and adds my new entry but the variables inside the Path have disappeared.
This is a problem because if a user changes the content of an environment variable referenced in the path the code will not longer find the correct location.

Is there any way to either:

- Get the Path environment variable without the internal variables getting expanded
- Append to the existing Path variable without loosing its current content as is.

Comment: Have you considered using [My.Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/objects/my-settings-object) to store the paths? Perhaps [VB.NET My.Settings deep dive](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/52295.vb-net-my-settings-deep-dive.aspx) gives some extra information that'll help.

Comment: You'll have to go through the Registry and get/set the `PATH` value. With .`OpenSubKey().GetValue("PATH", "", RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames)`, the variables are not expanded.

Comment: Setting the value in the registry sounds promising. I will try that as soon as i can. Thanks Jimi.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working reading and updating the Path environment variable directly from the registry as suggested by Jimmi above. This is the code. This version allows me to read the entries without the inside variables expanding and also save the values with environment variables if chosen by the user.

lstPathList is a listbox that already has all the existing entries in the Path environment variable.

```
Private Sub AddStringtoPath(value As String)
    Dim lPathVar As String = ""
    Dim Status As Integer = MsgBox("Modifying environment variables can cause side effects. Are you sure?", vbOKCancel)
    If Status = vbOK Then
        For a As Integer = 0 To lstPathList.Items.Count - 1
            If lstPathList.Items(a) = value Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                lPathVar = lPathVar + ";" + lstPathList.Items(a)
            End If
        Next
        lPathVar = lPathVar.Substring(1, lPathVar.Length - 1)
        lPathVar = lPathVar + ";" + value
        Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
        regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(
                            "System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment",
                            True)

        regKey.SetValue("Path", lPathVar)
        RefreshFormData()
    End If
End Sub
```